# Using regular expressions with C++ on Unix

Tags: c++, regex, unix

I'm familiar with Regex itself, but whenever I try to find any examples or documentation to use regex with Unix computers, I just get tutorials on how to write regex or how to use the .NET specific libraries available for Windows. I've been searching for a while and I can't find any good tutorials on C++ regex on Unix machines.

What I'm trying to do:

Parse a string using regex by breaking it up and then reading the different subgroups. To make a PHP analogy, something like preg_match that returns all $matches.

Comment: That'd be `preg_match_all(...)` then, not `preg_match(...)`.

Comment: Possibly because the C++ Standard does not specify any regular expression classes.

Comment: Neil,but after all php doesn't even provide standard ;-)

Comment: @Neil - but Posix does (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/regcomp.html).

Comment: PHP provides a better standard then C++ =P

Comment: Stanislav, as in "there's no standard like no standard"? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider using [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

An example (from the website):

```
bool validate_card_format(const std::string& s)
{
   static const boost::regex e("(\\d{4}[- ]){3}\\d{4}");
   return regex_match(s, e);
}
```

Another example:

```
// match any format with the regular expression:
const boost::regex e("\\A(\\d{3,4})[- ]?(\\d{4})[- ]?(\\d{4})[- ]?(\\d{4})\\z");
const std::string machine_format("\\1\\2\\3\\4");
const std::string human_format("\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4");

std::string machine_readable_card_number(const std::string s)
{
   return regex_replace(s, e, machine_format, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
}

std::string human_readable_card_number(const std::string s)
{
   return regex_replace(s, e, human_format, boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Look up the documentation for TR1 regexes or (almost equivalently) boost regex. Both work quite nicely on various Unix systems. The TR1 regex classes have been accepted into C++ 0x, so though they're not exactly part of the standard yet, they will be reasonably soon.

Edit: To break a string into subgroups, you can use an sregex_token_iterator. You can specify either what you want matched as tokens, or what you want matched as separators. Here's a quickie demo of both:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 

    std::string line;

    std::cout << "Please enter some words: " << std::flush;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::tr1::regex r("[ .,:;\\t\\n]+");
    std::tr1::regex w("[A-Za-z]+");

    std::cout << "Matching words:\n";
    std::copy(std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), w),
        std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::cout << "\nMatching separators:\n";
    std::copy(std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), r, -1), 
        std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

If you give it input like this: "This is some 999 text", the result is like this:

```
Matching words:
This
is
some
text

Matching separators:
This
is
some
999
text
```

Comment: He can also use Boost Xpressive (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/xpressive.html) which will get him compile-time error checking of his regular expressions. I doubt that will ever become standard though :)

Comment: This one is the most ideal imo. But I actually ran into it before and the server that I need to deply to doesn't support this. :/

Comment: @Manuel: Comment markdown syntax sucks sometimes, doesn't it? Also you're using 1.38?! Use `/release/` in boost URLs for the latest release version.

Comment: @Roger - Thanks, fixed. Strangely, the link to 1.38 was the first result on Google.

Comment: What I got out of regcomp, regexec is that they return 0 is its found. I need to return all the subgroups also.

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, Xpressive may be able to do the job. Depending on the details of what he wants, Boost Spririt::lex might also. Unless his needs are fairly specialized, however, the normal RE package is probably the first choice.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - agreed, I just thought that Xpressive deserved at least a mention :)

Comment: @Manuel: I tend to agree -- I probably should have mentioned at least a few more of the (admittedly many) possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [regcomp, regexec and regfree](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/regcomp.html).

One thing to be careful about is that the Posix regular expressions actually implement two different languages, regular (default) and extended (include the flag REG_EXTENDED in the call to regcomp).  If you are coming from the PHP world, the extended language closer to what you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

For perl-compatible regular expressions (pcre/preg), I'd suggest [boost.regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/).

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try [pcre](http://pcre.org/). And [pcrepp](http://mirror.daemon.de/idisk/pcre++/doc/classpcrepp_1_1Pcre.html).

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to have a look at this small color grep tool I wrote.

At [github](http://github.com/epatel/my_snippets/blob/master/C/cgrep/cgrep.c#LID52)

It uses regcomp, regexec and regfree that R Samuel Klatchko refers to.

Comment: Do you have any examples of returning the subgroups and manipulating them?

Comment: @Stanislav Palatnik Think that is handled on (around) line 95

Answer (score 0):

I use "GNU regex": http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Works well but can't find clear solution for UTF-8 regexp.

Regards